# QML TextField does not show copy menu on iOS

Tags: ios, qml, textfield

If I use default TextField control, default ios edit menu for copy/paste is displayed

```
TextField {
}
```

But I need TextField control without border, so I use TextFieldStyle

```
TextField {
    text: value
    style:  TextFieldStyle {
            background: Rectangle {
                border.width: 0
            }
    }
 }
```

In this case there is no ios edit menu fo copy/paste. Is possible to have default ios edit menu with TextField without border ?

Add: it works on iOS in **Qt 5.7.0**

Comment: Possible a ios specified bug. On Windows and Linux it works as expected.

Comment: On Android doesn't work too